# AMPscript SubString Starting Index

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Does the index start at 0 or at 1 for AMPscript?

`Substring(@str, 0, 1)` and `Substring(@str, 1, 1)` have the same result.

E.g. If `@str = "male"`. The result in both cases is `m`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review the help doc for the function : [Substring](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Substring.htm)

and reviewing the example and considering your test, it appears to start at 1

`%%=Substring('abcdef',2,2)=%%` returns `bc`

Comment: To add on to this instead of dilute with multiple answers - not exactly comprehensive or definitive, but it is explicitly stated in the IndexOf function that the index starts at 1 (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/IndexOf.htm)